# Angular not loading app.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

Im new to Angular and I started making a web application with springboot and downloaded a dashboard template (ngx-admin) which uses angular and typescript.
My problem is when i start my webserver and go to the url it just gives a loading page and doesnt load ngx-app which is devined as such in app.component.ts

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Akveo. All Rights Reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 */
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnalyticsService } from './@core/utils/analytics.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-app',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private analytics: AnalyticsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.analytics.trackPageViews();
  }
}
```

and in my html I call Loading...

Comment: can you post your index.html and app.module .. check in console there should be an error message

Comment: the problem here is with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` because the content inside router-outlet is only loaded from other component when you change or open any other route in your application.So if you only have a root url and no other routes in your application it will display the default `loading...` text.

Comment: you can try to change the template as below to see if it works ..
`template: '<h2>ngx app is running</h2>`

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` because the content inside router-outlet is only loaded from other component when you change or open any other route in your application.So if you only have a root url and no other routes in your application it will display the default `loading...` text.

you can try to change the template as below to see if it works ..

`template: '<h2>ngx app is running</h2>`